# SELECT from 2 with compare and if not

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have 2 tables, where I need to select all from AD_USERS, but if CN is equal to PrivilegeUserID in SITE_PRIVILEGE_MEMBERS and PrivilegeLevelID equals i.e 1 it should not be included:

**Table one:  (AD_USERS)**

- Columns:
- ID
- CN
- DisplayName
- mail
- ObjectGUID

**Table 2 : (SITE_PRIVILEGE_MEMBERS)**

Columns:

- ID
- PrivilegeUserID
- PrivilegeLevelID

.. How can I achive this in a SELECT?

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Data types, sample data and expected results help us help you. So does showing what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select *
from AD_USERS a
where not exists (
    select * from SITE_PRIVILEGE_MEMBERS m
    where m.ID=a.ID and a.CN=m.PrivilegeUserID and m.PrivilegeLevelID=1
)
```

Comment: BRILLIANT sTTu, that was it!! .. THANK YOU! :-) .. though b. need change to m. - just if others see this post.

Comment: Edited post, was a typo ;)